# My answer downvoted, then someone else posted same answer with upvote

Tags: discussion, voting

Just curious, as I understand that reputation is purely down to the community at large, but...

What's the deal with having an answer down voted, then immediately afterwards someone else posting the same answer (almost word for word) and it being upvoted?

Do we have any controls in place or is it just something to be accepted and move on?

Comment: It happens. Some people take reputation way too seriously - one downvote is not worth your time.

Comment: What @Oded said. It's not fair, but people do wacky things for reputation, including against others. For example, there is anecdotal evidence many moderators get random down votes from people they bust for cheating for votes. Not fair, but it's one minor downside to things. The upside outweighs it all, though!

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I figured it was something like that.

Comment: The person who downvoted your answer is likely not the person who upvoted the other answer.